# SSL wrapped socket isnt allowing client connections in Python, unwrapped allows connections which then send TLS handshake packets

Tags: python, ssl, python-asyncio

I am writing an async server that will accept connections from IoT devices and control them. The IoT devices have their DNS overridden to point their cloud domain to a local host.

I can MITM traffic between device and cloud server using socat and a self signed cert. When I try and setup asyncio.start_server with a ssl_context that uses the cert and key files, I get no connections at all. When I run the server without SSL, I get connections from the IoT devices but, they only repeatedly send TLS client hello packets.

The devices are sending a TLS handshake but it seems I have misconfigured something with my SSL socket. Please help me understand what I am doing incorrectly.

---

Create Cert/Key

```
mkdir -p certs
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout certs/key.pem -out certs/cert.pem -subj '/CN=*.xlink.cn' -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes
cat certs/key.pem certs/cert.pem > certs/server.pem
```

---

Example SSL script

```
import logging
import socket
import ssl
import asyncio
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)04d %(levelname)s - %(name)s %(module)s:%(lineno)d -> %(message)s",
    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",
)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    msgs = 0
    while True:
        if msgs:
            break
        data = await reader.read(100)
        if data:
            msgs += 1
            addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

            logger.info(f"Received from {addr!r} => {data}")

    logger.info("Closing the connection")
    writer.close()


async def main():
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile="certs/cert.pem", keyfile="certs/key.pem")
    # dont create the socket and wrap it yourself, pass ctx and it is handled for us.
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_client, "0.0.0.0", 23779, ssl=ssl_context
    )

    sock = server.sockets[0]
    addr = sock.getsockname()
    logger.info(f"Serving on {addr}")

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.debug("Starting SSL server...")
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

Example Non SSL script

```
import logging
import ssl
import asyncio
import sys

CERT = 'certs/cert.pem'
KEY = 'certs/key.pem'
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 23779

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)04d %(levelname)s - %(name)s %(module)s:%(lineno)d -> %(message)s",
    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",
)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    msgs = 0
    while True:
        if msgs:
            break
        data = await reader.read(100)
        if data:
            msgs += 1
            addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

            logger.info(f"Received from {addr!r} => {data}")

    logger.info("Closing the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_client, HOST, PORT)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    logger.info(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.debug("Starting server with no SSL")
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When Running the SSL script I get no connections:

```
❯ python3 cync-lan
02/20/24 11:40:27.0934 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:47 -> Serving on ('0.0.0.0', 23779)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/baudneo/cync-lan", line 50, in main
    await server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 369, in serve_forever
    await self._serving_forever_fut
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/baudneo/cync-lan", line 54, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 123, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

---

When I run the non SSL script, I get devices connecting and repeatedly sending TLS client hello packets

```
❯ python3 cync-lan
02/20/24 11:19:38.0601 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:42 -> Serving on ('0.0.0.0', 23779)
02/20/24 11:19:38.0959 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:32 -> Received from ('10.0.1.168', 64161) => b'\x16\x03\x01\x00S\x01\x00\x00O\x03\x03\xe2\x9b\xad{5\x10 }>\xfb\xa6{U~\xa0xPK\xa3{\xe5I zg\x93\xa1{\xbdR {\x00\x00\n\x00=\x005\x00<\x00/\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x00\r\x00\x0c\x00\n\x06\x01\x05\x01\x04\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00'
02/20/24 11:19:38.0959 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:34 -> Closing the connection
02/20/24 11:19:39.0184 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:32 -> Received from ('10.0.1.170', 58668) => b'\x16\x03\x01\x00S\x01\x00\x00O\x03\x03\xd2\x002L\xae(\xb8r\x86\x96\xb6w8\x82\xb3p,\xdd4rsW\xb6qy\xf8\xb5p\xd6\xfd4q\x00\x00\n\x00=\x005\x00<\x00/\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x00\r\x00\x0c\x00\n\x06\x01\x05\x01\x04\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00'
02/20/24 11:19:39.0184 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:34 -> Closing the connection
02/20/24 11:19:40.0287 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:32 -> Received from ('10.0.1.167', 63770) => b'\x16\x03\x01\x00S\x01\x00\x00O\x03\x03\xff\x07\xb4t7~>vN\x9a<s*\xa69r\x16\x94\xb8p$\n:p\xba\x93:q#\xdc;q\x00\x00\n\x00=\x005\x00<\x00/\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x00\r\x00\x0c\x00\n\x06\x01\x05\x01\x04\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00'
02/20/24 11:19:40.0287 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:34 -> Closing the connection
02/20/24 11:19:40.0398 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:32 -> Received from ('10.0.1.169', 63696) => b'\x16\x03\x01\x00S\x01\x00\x00O\x03\x03\x1b\xeaXP\xdb\x0cU@=l\xd5F]\x9f\xd3F\xae\xaf\xd3E\x1e\xd6\xd0Eg\x8ePD\xbf2QD\x00\x00\n\x00=\x005\x00<\x00/\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x00\r\x00\x0c\x00\n\x06\x01\x05\x01\x04\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00'
02/20/24 11:19:40.0398 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:34 -> Closing the connection
02/20/24 11:19:52.0992 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:32 -> Received from ('10.0.1.168', 64162) => b'\x16\x03\x01\x00S\x01\x00\x00O\x03\x03\x18?\x8fb\xf5\xed\x06u\xa7\x1b\x81qQ\xb2\x05r\xf8I\x06p\x83\x1d\x84qW\xa0\x85p\xea\xca\x04p\x00\x00\n\x00=\x005\x00<\x00/\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x00\r\x00\x0c\x00\n\x06\x01\x05\x01\x04\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00'
02/20/24 11:19:52.0992 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:34 -> Closing the connection
02/20/24 11:19:55.0429 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:32 -> Received from ('10.0.1.167', 63771) => b'\x16\x03\x01\x00S\x01\x00\x00O\x03\x03\x92\xb0\x13n~\xe8\x1cz&\x9e\x98}P2\x9f\x7f\xfc\t\x1d|\xc7\xdf\x1e}\x91\xc2\x9f|\x8ci\x1e|\x00\x00\n\x00=\x005\x00<\x00/\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x00\r\x00\x0c\x00\n\x06\x01\x05\x01\x04\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00'
02/20/24 11:20:25.0523 INFO - __main__ cync-lan:34 -> Closing the connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a ciphers issue:

```
       ciphers = [
        "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
        "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
        "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
        "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA",
        "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA",
        "ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA",
        "AES256-GCM-SHA384",
        "AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "AES256-SHA256",
        "AES128-SHA256",
        "AES256-SHA",
        "AES128-SHA",
        "DES-CBC3-SHA",
    ]
    ssl_context.set_ciphers(":".join(ciphers))
```

To debug the root issue I wrote a different script:

```
import logging
import socket
import ssl
import sys

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 23779
CERT = "certs/cert.pem"
KEY = "certs/key.pem"


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)04d %(levelname)s - %(name)s %(module)s:%(lineno)d -> %(message)s",
    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",
)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def start_tls_server(host, port, certfile, keyfile):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)

    logger.debug(f"Listening on {host}:{port}...")

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        logger.debug(f"Accepted connection from {addr}")
        ssl_socket = None

        try:
            ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
            ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
            ssl_socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(
                client_socket, server_side=True, do_handshake_on_connect=False
            )
            ssl_socket.do_handshake()
            logger.debug(f"SSL connection established with {addr}")
        except ssl.SSLError as e:
            logger.debug(f"TLS Handshake failed: {e}")
        finally:
            if ssl_socket is not None:
                ssl_socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_tls_server(HOST, PORT, CERT, KEY)
```